# Uncaught Syntax Error & Manifest Syntax Error

Tags: reactjs, manifest.json

I did a react project for my bootcamp, and just pulled it down from my github again, after running `npm i` and `npm run-script build` I am getting a white screen with 3 errors in the console. 2 of the errors are `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` and the other is `Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.`

These errors are not showing on the deployed version, and I am wondering how to get rid of them so I can start working on it on my local host.

Repo: https://github.com/childishmartino/Book-Search-Engine

Comment: You should post the code causing the problem, and a more complete version of the errors you are getting.

Comment: @gunwin Unfortunately those errors are exactly how they appear in the console, so its the complete errors. Additionally I posted the repo that I am having issues cloning and then running, I dont know the specific piece of code in in that I need to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your project has three package.json files.

- ./package.json
- ./Client/package.json
- ./Server/package.json

The package.json at the root level has a script `install` that navigates to the other folders and installs the packages. You should run both `npm i` at the root to install those packages, and either `npm i` in each of the sub-folders, or your script, `npm run install` at the root to install everything required. Then `npm run develop` to start the applications.

I cloned you project, and was able to run successfully using Node 14.7.4

Comment: thank you soo much! running `npm run develop` got it all working!

Answer (score 0):

You should run
`npm run install` as this is a script that installs the node modules both in the server and client directory.

`npm i` installs the scripts in the root directory, that's why you get those errors.

Comment: I recloned the repo again and ran both `npm run install` and and `npm i` on the new clone and I am still experiencing the same issue after running `npm run build`